# ASCII number pattern matching in binary file in Python 2

Tags: binary, pattern-matching, python-2.6

I'm trying to read a binary file and match number(s) in each of its records.
If the number matches then the record is to be copied to another file.
the number should be present in between 24th to 36th byte of each record.

The script takes the numbers as arguments. Here's the script I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# search.py

import re
import glob
import os
import binascii
list = sys.argv[1:]

list.sort()

rec_len=452

filelist = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '*.bin')

print('Input File : %s' % filelist)

for file in filelist:
    outfile =  file + '.out'

    f = open(file, "rb")
    g = open(outfile, "wb")

    for pattern in list:

        print pattern
        regex_search = re.compile(pattern).search

        while True:
            buf = f.read(rec_len)
            if len(buf) == 0:
                 break
            else:
                match = regex_search(buf)
                match2=buf.find(pattern)
                #print match
                #print match2
                if ((match2 != -1) | (match != None )):
                    g.write(buf)

    f.close()
    g.close()
print ("Done")
```

I'm running it like:

```
python search.py 1234 56789
```

I'm using python 2.6.
The code is not matching the number.
I also tried using binascii to convert the number to binary before matching but even then it didn't return any record.

If I give any string it works correctly but If i give any number as argument it doesn't match.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are *depleting* the filebuffer by reading all the bytes in the check for the first pattern. Hence, the 2nd pattern will never be matched (an attempt will not even be made), because you've already reached the end of the file, by reading all the records during the for-loop run of the first pattern.

That means that if your first pattern is nowhere to be found in those records, your script will not give you any output.

Consider adding `f.seek(0)` at the end of the while loop, or changing the order of the two loop constructs such that you *first* read a record from the file, *then* match the regex for each of the patterns in the argument list.

Also, try not to shadow the python builtins by using `list` for the name of an array. It won't give you problems in the code you've shown, but it's definitely something you should be aware of.